# Linux: mmap() for non-regular files

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mmap

I understand that mmap() allows an application to map a file into memory, so that there's a one-on-one correspondence between a memory address and a word in the file.

But my question is what if the file is a non-regular file created by a device driver? As I know, some non-regular files are mmap-able, some are not. What does that mean from programming's perspective? What should I do if I want my non-regular file to be mmap-able?

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on a Linux-kernel-module in which I implemented mmap function pointer(struct file_operations). This module would create a device entry in /dev/ directory. Now my user-space application would open this entry using "open" and would make a mmap system call. Eventually inside the Linux-Kernel-module I insmoded the mmap function will be called and will do the implemented processing and will return back to the user-space.

This was just an example to represent the service requested by the user-space to the OS(Kernel).
When ever user wants to access hardware or wants to request service from the kernel(like mapping physical memory to user-virtual-address-space), it can do it using the entry created by the driver in the /dev/ or /sys/ or /proc/ etc. These files can be termed as "virtual interface" to the kernel.